# Как можно добавить в меню елементам li - класс

Tags: php, wordpress

Как можно добавить в меню первым шести li определеный класс используя wp_nav_menu
html:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'menuOne', 'container'=>'false', 'menu_class'=>'cf')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo str_replace('class="menu-item', 'class="menu-item CLASSNAME', wp_nav_menu( array( 'echo' => 0, ) ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Так, если добавление определенного класса необходимо для придания стилей, то вы можете использовать css псевдоклассы. Например li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2)....